# Как осуществить вход через модальную форму?

Tags: php, javascript

У меня реализован паттерн MVC (самописка).
В сети куча модальных форм входа на HTML + CSS, но нет инфы как передавать управление на сервер.
Вот пример формы входа, которую я выбрал:

## Авторизация

Войти через:

Нет аккаунта? Регистрация.
              Забыли пароль?

## Регистрация

Войти через:

Уже зарегистрированы? Войти.

Но! у меня авторизацией занимается контроллер UsersController.
Как передать ему введенные данные? Как в результате проверки или вывести ту же форму авторизации с сообщением об ошибке (если ошибка), или войти на сайт, если все ОК?
Буд благодарен за любые ссылки или ответы.

Comment: У меня реализован паттерн MVC (самописка).
В сети куча модальных форм входа на HTML + CSS, но нет инфы как передавать управление на сервер.

Но! у меня авторизацией занимается контроллер UsersController.
Как передать ему введенные данные? Как в результате проверки или вывести ту же форму авторизации с сообщением об ошибке (если ошибка), или войти на сайт, если все ОК?
Буд благодарен за любые ссылки или ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать посредством Ajax запроса, таким образом: вводишь данные в форму, по клике на кнопку войти собираешь логин пароль с формы, и отправляешь на сервер, например в определенный файл идентификации пользователей (пускай будет `auth.php`). В нем ты подключаешь свой файл и передаешь в него параметры пришедшие от клиента. У тебя за это должен отвечать твой контроллер.

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
// проверить входные параметры на валидность, а так же экранировать
```

Далее отправить:

```
$res = $db->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = $login and password = md5($password) LIMIT 1'


$isAuth = false;
if (sizeOf($res) == 1) {
 // пользователь найден,  авторизовать =>>
  $isAuth = true;
}
```

Если такие пользователи есть тебе вернется хотя бы один результат. Ну тут сравнение и возвращение результата (лучше в `json`, типа: `{isAuth: $isAuth}`)

А на клиенте уже проверять, на `$.ajax.success` если тебе вернулся `res.isAuth == true` то авторизовать (заполнить куку и т.д).

Comment: А иначе у тебя будут отправляться данные, перезагружаться страница (полностью), там где то ты поставишь условие, если у тебя была отправка авторизации => открыть модальное окно и вывести в него какое то сообщение о не правильности/не существующего пользователя